# The value of |$ \lambda$| is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, maxima-minima

[image: This is the question.]

Can anyone help me type this stuff out? I am new to MathJax. 
Also, I have no idea what to do in the question. Seems really complicated.

Comment: Just plug the values into the functions.

Comment: Thanks @kingW3. I'll try it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugging the values into the functions, we have, $$g (5,-3) =8$$ $$g (-1.25, 14.75) =16$$ $$f (8, 16) =16 =2^4 =2^{2^{2}} =(-2)^{(-2)^{2}} = \lambda^{\lambda^{2}} $$ Thus $$|\lambda|=2$$

Comment: Thanks mate! I didn't know it was this easy. It looked much more complicated :P